# Best Method to Insert 1-2MB images to SQL table

Tags: asp.net, sql, .net, vb.net, crystal-reports

I am trying to find the best method to insert images of size 1-2 mb to SQL and maintain the best possible resolution and original for the pictures. The problem is that when I view the image in Crystal Report, it would change the solution of report (Even though I checked "Retain image quality") and in many cases it would stretch the images size and make the images wider. Please advice.

Comment: I imagine you'd store the images as blob fields, since they're pretty small.  You *could* use something like `FILESTREAM` as well, which has its pros and cons.  But from the application perspective there wouldn't be a difference.  You're asking two questions here... Do you want to know how to store an image or are you having trouble maintaining the aspect ratio of stored images in your output?  What are you asking?  If the latter, can you demonstrate and show the code/setup you're using?

Comment: Thank you Dave. I am having trouble maintaining the aspect ratio of stored images in my Crystal Report (Version 9). I am inserting the images using the image type in SQL table. What is the best method for inserting the images in asp.net (using vb) to SQL filed and what datatype should I use? (All considering the fact that I need to maintain the original size, resolution ,etc of the images)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to maintain entire integrity of the images and if you have access to the filesystem, the best way I can think of is to copy the file into some directory and then store only the path (and any other properties you deem appropriate) in the database. Then you have entire control over usage of these images. (And you also keep your database size down).

The only thing to watch out for is making sure your database does not retain dangling file paths (clear database rows at the time of image deletion).

Comment: Yes, but I dont know how to do this in Crystal 9!